# Python : MySQLdb cursorclass returns tuples instead of dictionary when set as MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor

Tags: python, mysql

So I am trying to retrieve data from database with MySQLdb in pandas dataframe.

```
import MySQLdb as mysqldb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import pandas as pd

def connection():
     db = mysqldb.connect(
             host="123.456.7.890",
             user="user",
             passwd="password",
             db="database",
             port=12345,
             cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
     )
     return db

mysql = connection()

def testing():
    cur = mysql.cursor()

    query = cur.execute("select * from table1")
    result = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()

    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    return result_df
```

When I print the 'testing' function, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xx/PycharmProjects/practice/python.py", line 97, in <module>
    print(testing())
  File "C:/Users/xx/PycharmProjects/practice/python.py", line 94, in testing
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\practice\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 422, in __init__
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I put cursorclass to MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor to get the data in dictionary form but instead it seems like I'm getting them in tuple. Currently using python 3.7.

It works when I use pymysql but seems quite slow.

Comment: What is the value of the `result`?

Comment: result contains ID numbers, names, money amount and date registered.

Comment: I know the way to get the values of the db without using DataFrame...by using pymysql

Comment: pymysql seems quite slow so I tried using MySQLdb but got that error...